# How do I fix mysqli_store_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given

Tags: php, mysqli

I have looked at the manual for the function and cannot figure out what parameter would satisfy. I know several other questions have this problem but none of those solutions have helped.
Here is my code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "first_db");
mysqli_select_db($link, "first_db");
$query = mysqli_query($link, "Select * from list WHERE id ='$id'");
$count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: where is your  `mysqli_store_result()` method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are calling `mysqli_query` you don't actually need to call `mysqli_store_result` as that is part of what that does (see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)). Also since you're not actually using a prepared statement you need to change the `num_rows` routine you are calling; replace

```
$count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($query);
```

with

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```